# Prove that the expression is a whole number

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic

Let $\;q\in\mathbb{N}\;,\;q\geqslant2\;$ and $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;,\;n\geqslant1.$

Prove that for all $\;m\in\mathbb{N}$ :

$\alpha_m=\dfrac{(q^m-1)(q^m-q)\cdot\ldots\cdot(q^m-q^{n-1})}{(q^n-1)(q^n-q)\cdot\ldots\cdot(q^n-q^{n-1})}\in \mathbb{N}\;.$

There is a hint given: start by dealing with the case $\;q=p^i\;$ with $\;p\;$ prime and $\;i\geqslant1.$

I have tried a few routes ( including induction starting with $\;m\geqslant n\;$ because $\;m<n\;$ yields $\;0\;$ straight away ), but I cannot quite bridge every gaps. This question is from “Agregation externe 2021 : question III-12-a”.

By induction, I have tried to prove that:

$\alpha_m \in \mathbb{N}$ and is a multiple of $(q^{m-n}+q^{m-n-1}+...+1)$

$\alpha_n=1$, and I end up with $\alpha_{m+1}=\frac{q^m+q^{m-1}+...+1}{q^{m-n}+q^{m-n-1}+...+1}\alpha_m$, so $\alpha_{m+1} \in \mathbb{N}$ but I am missing the second part of the induction hypothesis.

Also, I am not using the hint, which makes me think this is not the right way to proceed...

Comment: If $q=p^i$, the number to be computed is the number of subspaces of dimension $n$ in a linear space of dimension $m$ over the finite field of dimension $q=p^i$.

Comment: "I cannot quite bridge every gap."  Cn you give us some idea of how close you can get, and what the gaps you need to bridge are?

Comment: @saulpatz: I have added to my post the induction that I have tried without success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

Denote
$$\binom{m}{n}_q= \dfrac{(q^m-1)(q^m-q)\cdot\ldots\cdot(q^m-q^{n-1})}{(q^n-1)(q^n-q)\cdot\ldots\cdot(q^n-q^{n-1})}.$$

$\binom{m}{n}_q$ is called the [Gaussian binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient?wprov=sfti1).

One can prove the relations

$$\binom{m}{n}_q= \frac{q^m-1}{q^n-1}\binom{m-1}{n-1}_q$$ and
$$\binom{m}{n}_q=q^n \binom{m-1}{n}_q+ \binom{m-1}{n-1}_q$$
enabling to prove that those numbers are natural numbers by induction.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be working indeed. I will make the effort to write it properly tomorrow. However, I am still curious about the hint regarding the use of power of primes...

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this was precisely Gauss' original approach (see https://eudml.org/doc/203313), except he used the similar identity ${m \choose n}_q = {m-1 \choose n}_q + q^{m-n} {m-1 \choose n-1}_q$.